# Event-based JOb scheduling

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a requirement to generate certain reports as and when the DB is updated (say new alerts have been generated or new users have been created etc). I have MySQL DB triggers that get fired when the tables get updated and my question is can I schedule a job that gets executed whenever the DB trigger fires off?

This is Java Spring based application and I am considering Quartz but so far I haven't been able to figure out if Quartz can trigger jobs based on DB triggers. I have come across a 'jBatchEngine' that says "In contrast to time driven schedulers like Cron, jBatchEngine is event driven". Has anyone done such event-based job scheduling with Quartz or any other tools? Please advise !!

Thanks much !!!

Comment: I found this: http://markmail.org/message/ka4sijpxsrpn7akz